# Campaign Monitor importing template: unsubscript tag not found

Tags: campaign-monitor

I try to import an email-template in campaign monitor, but it shows always the same problem:
No unsubscribe link  We require a single-click unsubscribe link in every campaign you send. Please add the tags  and  around the words you want to become an unsubscribe link.

What I do not understand is, that I have the tag in my template:

```
<layout label="POST-FOOTER25">
            <table width="100%" bgcolor="#fff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="backgroundTable">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td width="100%">
                        <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="devicewidthinner">
                           <tbody>
                              <!-- Top Spacing -->
                              <tr>
                                 <td width="100%" height="10" style="font-size: 0;line-height: 0;border-collapse: collapse;">&nbsp;</td>
                              </tr>
                              <!-- Top Spacing -->
                              <tr>
                                 <td width="100%">
                                    <table width="560" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="devicewidthinner">
                                       <tbody class="">
                                          <tr class="">
                                             <td width="100%" align="right" valign="middle" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 16px; color: rgb(62, 69, 76); text-align: center; font-weight: 400;" mgedit="text" class="aligncenter">
                                                <multiline label="text617_86">
                                                   <!--[if !mso]><!-->
                                                   <span style="font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;">
                                                      <!--<![endif]-->
                                                        You are receiving this email because you subscribed for updates on our website. <unsubscribe>Click here to Unsubscribe</unsubscribe><br /><br />
                                                      <preferences>Manage your subscription</preferences>
                                                      <!--[if !mso]><!-->
                                                   </span>
                                                   <!--<![endif]-->
                                                </multiline>
                                             </td>
                                          </tr>
                                       </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                              <!-- Bottom Spacing -->
                              <tr>
                                 <td width="100%" height="10" style="font-size: 0;line-height: 0;border-collapse: collapse;">&nbsp;</td>
                              </tr>
                              <!-- Bottom Spacing -->
                           </tbody>
                        </table>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </layout>
```

There is no comment or if-case around the unsubscribe-tag. Any other idea?

Greets, yab86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend moving the unsubscribe and preferences markup out of the multiline markup area. It's likely their system doesn't recognize it because it's put into the editable multiline WYSIWYG Editor

Comment: Thank you Alex. The problem was, that the unsubscribe-tag should be after the </repeater> and in addition as you said, with no multiline markup.